# Vectorization of Matlab Code involving ODE solver at each iteration

Tags: performance, optimization, vectorization, fast-enumeration, ode

I want to write a fast MATLAB code where I need to write a for loop and  I need to solve an ordinary differential equation each time.Is there any way to vectorize the code?
Following is the part of the code:

```
       tspan=0:0.01:20;
        dw=rand(p,1);
        M0=repmat([0 0 1],p,1)';
        for p=1:ns
       [t,M(:,:,p)]=ode45(@(t,M) testfun(t,M,dw(p)),tspan,M0(:,p));
       end
```

where

```
       function  dM=testfun(t,M,w1) 
      M_x=M(1);
      M_y=M(2);
       M_z=M(3);
      dM=[w1*M_y;-w1*M_x+w1*M_z-2*w1*M_y;-w1*M_y-(1-M_z)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know how it works.

- right hand side of the ODE system:

  ```
      function  dM = testfun(t,M,w1)

        dM = zeros(length(M), 1);

        M_x  =  M(1:3:end, 1);
        M_y  =  M(2:3:end, 1);
        M_z  =  M(3:3:end, 1);

       dM(1:3:end)  =              (w1.*M_y)';
       dM(2:3:end)  = (-w1.*M_x - 2*w1.*M_y + w1.*M_z)';
       dM(3:3:end)  =             (-w1.*M_y -  (1-M_z))';
     end
  ```
- main program:

  `clear all`
  `clc`

  `ns = input('Please tell me how many time you need to integrate the ODE system: ');`

  `tspan =  0:0.01:20;`

  `dw    =  rand(ns,1);`

  `M0    =  repmat([0; 0; 1], 1, ns);`

  `[t, my_M] = ode45(@(t,my_M) testfun(t,my_M,dw), tspan, M0);`

  `s = size(my_M);`

  `for i = 1:ns`

  ```
      M(:, 1:s(2)/ns, i) = my_M(:, s(2)/ns*(i-1)+1:s(2)/ns*i);
  ```

  `end`

Comment: Thank you a lot...sorry for being late to thank you... but it will help me anyway...

Comment: The next question arises... is it possible to solve this same system if w1 varies with time step without interpolating w1 in the ODE function?because it is highly time consuming